# Help with translating this assembly into c

Tags: c++, assembly, translation, pic, status-register

My compiler won't work with an assembly file I have and my other compiler that will won't work with the c files I have.  I don't understand assembly.  I need to move this over but I'm not getting anywhere fast. Is there someone out there that can help?  I can't believe there isn't a translator available.  Here is the beginning of the file:

```
    list        p=18F4480       
    #include    <p18F4480.inc> 

    #define _Z      STATUS,2
    #define _C      STATUS,0

    GLOBAL  AARGB0,AARGB1,AARGB2,AARGB3     
    GLOBAL  BARGB0,BARGB1,BARGB2,BARGB3
    GLOBAL  ZARGB0,ZARGB1,ZARGB2
    GLOBAL  REMB0,REMB1
    GLOBAL  TEMP,TEMPB0,TEMPB1,TEMPB2,TEMPB3
    GLOBAL  LOOPCOUNT,AEXP,CARGB2


LSB         equ 0
MSB         equ 7

math_data   UDATA   
AARGB0      RES 1       
AARGB1      RES 1
AARGB2      RES 1
AARGB3      RES 1
BARGB0      RES 1   
BARGB1      RES 1
BARGB2      RES 1
BARGB3      RES 1
REMB0       RES 1   
REMB1       RES 1
REMB2       RES 1
REMB3       RES 1   
TEMP        RES 1
TEMPB0      RES 1
TEMPB1      RES 1
TEMPB2      RES 1
TEMPB3      RES 1
ZARGB0      RES 1
ZARGB1      RES 1
ZARGB2      RES 1
CARGB2      RES 1
AEXP        RES 1
LOOPCOUNT   RES 1


math_code   CODE
;---------------------------------------------------------------------
;       24-BIT ADDITION             
_24_BitAdd
    GLOBAL  _24_BitAdd
    movf    BARGB2,w
    addwf   AARGB2,f

    movf    BARGB1,w
    btfsc   _C
    incfsz  BARGB1,w
    addwf   AARGB1,f

    movf    BARGB0,w
    btfsc   _C
    incfsz  BARGB0,w
    addwf   AARGB0,f
    return
```

I get that I can largly exclude the first two lines as the device defines are in my main.c anyway.  The two #defines are just that, but the simplest way (I think) is to just replace instances of _Z and _C with STATUS,2 and STATUS,0 accordingly.  The next lines (the GLOBALs) are simply variable declarations I'm gathering.  Same with LSB and MSB except they also assign values.  The next chunck I think I just declare a bunch of integers with those names (AARGB0, etc) and then the chunck after that is a function.

I don't even bother to translate that function, because my compiler has #asm/#end asm directives so I can put it in raw (as long as its wrapped in a function).

I think I have it all... until I build and my compiler screams about STATUS not being defined.  And of course its not.  But what is it?  I read on the net that STATUS registers are something special but I really don't get how it works.

If you haven't noticed, I'm not even sure what it is I'm really asking.  I just want the bloody thing to work.

Comment: Here's the translation: `return AARGB + BARGB;`

Comment: If you know that what you are asking is unclear, you shouldn't be asking. Try to structure questions in the following form: this is what I do - this is what happens - this is what I want to happen instead.

Comment: What are you *really* trying to do? I'm guessing this is an excerpt from some set of assembly routines to perform 24-bit arithmetic. If that's what you really want to do (perform 24-bit arithmetic), then perhaps that's what you should ask about.

Comment: I'm going to guess that your question is along the lines of "I need a math package in my C program but the one that I have is written in assembler".

Comment: No, neither of you are correct on "why".  I get that I wasn't clear, and you're right - perhaps I shouldn't have asked. I was so frustrated at getting nowhere for 3 days straight.  In fact the particular exerpt above is just some fraction of the code I was trying to utilize. The math portion is pretty insignificant, it was just the simplest exerpt to deal with.  I was just looking for hints on how to proceed.  Forget about it though.  I just coded it all from scratch and said "screw it" to not reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

STATUS is a built-in register in the PIC architecture, that implements the same functionality as the "status" or "condition" flags register in most larger CPU:s. It contains bitflags that are set and cleared by the microcontroller as it executes code, telling you the result of operations.

The Z flag, for instance, is set whenever an arithmetic operation results in a zero, and the C (carry) flag is set when arithmetic overflow is detected.

These are flags that are typically not visible from C, as C doesn't want to require that the host processor even *has* status bits, so directly translating this code to C will be hard. You will need to figure out a way to include the status-reading bit tests in the C code, and use those instructions when possible. This might be troublesome, as from C you have less control over which registers are being used, which in turn might make it hard to make sure you're checking the proper flags in the right place(s).

[Here](http://www.massmind.org/techref/microchip/math/add/index.htm) are a few links to other people's extended precision PIC code. Most seem to remain in assembly, but they might still be useful as references or inspiration.

Answer (score 6):

Your compilers are refusing your source?

Either you are using broken tools, or your source files are buggy. In both cases, your problem is not "translating ASM to C" or something like that, but the bugs in your source / toolchain. Do not try to work around problems, solve them.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to reverse-engineer the disassembly.  But what will you learn?

You should be able to compile your assembly (using compiler 1) into an object file, and link that to the object file compiled by compiler 2 from your C file.

Comment: Yes!  I *should* be able to!  That's why I've been pulling my hair out.  The compiler I'm using (and I don't want to change) appears to be entirely incompatible with the object files generated by the assembler, despite documents to the contrary in its help file.  The company that makes it is looking into it but so far I've heard nothing.